# Run Graspit! with plugin

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to use Graspit! in ros. But I couldn't launch Graspit! with plugins. I have tried rosrun graspit graspit plugin: and it didn't work. Does anyone have experience with running Graspit! with plugins? Thank you very very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48120/run-graspit!-with-plugin/) by [shuai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3402/shuai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I couldn't get this working either. I looked through the source and it seems that there is a bug in the graspitGUI.cpp code for loading plugins on the command line. The problem is here starting at **line 155 in graspitGUI.cpp**:

```
//look for plugins of the form plugin:name in the arguments
for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
QString arg(argv[i]);
if (arg.section(',',0,0)=="plugin") {
  QString libName = arg.section(',',1,1);
  std::cout << "Processing arguments \n ";
  PluginCreator* creator = PluginCreator::loadFromLibrary(libName.toStdString());     
  if (creator) {
    mPluginCreators.push_back(creator);
  } else {
    DBGA("Failed to load plugin: " << libName.latin1());
  }
}
```

This shows that "**if (arg.section(',',0,0)=="plugin")**" and "**QString libName = arg.section(',',1,1);**" are actually looking for an argument of the form "**plugin,name**" versus "plugin:name"

So, just change your argument to "**plugin,name**" to get it to run for now I guess... Or, recompile with the commas replaced with colons.

-Michael

---

Originally posted by [m.anderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2685/m.anderson/) with karma: 91 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0